# How to to write Computed_field code?

Tags: 7, database

I'm testing the computed_field module on a taxonomy field. I want to get the number of nodes that have a term reference to the current term:

```
$tid = 1;
$entity_field[0]['value'] =  db_query("
SELECT count(*)
FROM node n INNER JOIN taxonomy_index t on n.nid = t.nid
WHERE n.type = 'discussion'
and n.status = 1
and t.tid=$tid")->fetchField();
```

How can I get the tid of the term? Is there a better way of writing the query?

Answer (score 1):

A query like that should do the trick, but if you want something more elegant, I recommend [EntityFieldQuery](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21entity.inc/class/EntityFieldQuery/7).